# Injected value is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 with options API.

As shown in the code below, I am trying to pass map object from the provider component to the injector component so that the map object should be reactive.
I do not get any error from the provider component, but in the injector component the log message displays undefined

How can I correctly pass the value of the map object using provide/inject?

Provider component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async renderMap() {
            map = mapViewModel.getMap();
            provide(SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description, computed(()=> map));
        }
    }
}
```

Injector component:

```
const mapInstance = inject(SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description);

export default {
    methods: {
        onDigitizePolygon() {
            console.info(debugTag, 'mapInstance:', mapInstance);
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're sending the data from parent to child. If you want to do the opposite, I recommend using a store structure like pinia. Provide/inject structure exists to provide data flow from parent to child. In the code you shared, the provider component parent and the component child that is the injector play smoothly.

Comment: but why the value of mapInstance is undefined?am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you provide from child(low-level component), you can not inject the provided value from parent component. Its about rendering cycle.

Comment: the provider is the parent and the injector is the chils

Comment: try to provide in the created/mounted cycle and update its value

Comment: i am make the provide in mounted() and inside nextTick!!??

Comment: Provide computed value in mounted. And inject value in mounted. Then just update map value in the provider component. Because of the provided value is computed, its has to be updated in injector component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255030/discussion-between-tanzer-atay-and-amrmsmb).